# Is it possible to still get royalties in an outright sell / assignment of your patent deal?

Tags: patents

If you sell your patent completely for a large lump sum, is it still possible to work royalties into that deal somehow?

Comment: During the contract negotiations, of course you can try.

Comment: Is that common? How successful is this strategy?

Comment: I assume it's your patent now and the other party is interested in acquiring it.  So you have some negotiating to do here.  You want some money up front but you also want an ongoing revenue stream.  The other party likely wants a done deal with no ongoing expense.  So you will need to find a mutually acceptable middle ground where you get what you want and they get what they want.  Make a proposal and see where it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you sell it, you don’t own it

That’s what “sell” means. So, once you’ve sold your patent for a lump sum, it’s no longer your patent and you no longer have any rights to it. This includes the right to licence it’s use for royalties.

If you are actually asking if you can licence its use for an up-front lump sum *and* ongoing royalties, then, yes.